# Google Guice Injection of Class With Injected Members

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, factory

I'm a fairly experienced programmer but I'm fairly new to Guice and I'm not sure what the best practices are. Here is my possibly flawed understanding so far, please point out if I use incorrect terminology, question follows after:

Classes with a (public) no arguments constructor or an `@Inject`-annotated constructor (there may be only one such constructor) do not need to be explicitly bound/provided in the module. Though in the latter case, of course, the constructor parameters may need to be explicitly provided unless they can also be auto-provided by the same rule.

When instances of such classes are (automatically) provided, this can always be thought of as being done in `injector.getInstance(...)` fashion – `@Inject`-annotated members (like say injected private fields in the class, see my `Car` example) will also be injected and not left null.

The above two facts(?) partially solve the problem that one can not explicitly bind/provide an instance with `@Inject`-annotated members, since one can not create an instance inside a provider using `injector.getInstance(...)` and so the `@Inject`-annotated members will be left null.

The remaining problem case is when the constructor requires one or more parameters to be given during creation, the values of which cannot be known up front and therefore cannot be injected.

The solution generally seems to be to provide/inject a factory with a parameterized create method to create the instances when and as needed, but this could only be done using `new`, which does not work in general – what if the class contains `@Inject`-annotated members itself? Constructing the class with `new` will leave those should-be-injected members null-valued.

Here is sample code:

```java
class Car {

    @Inject
    private Engine engine;

    ...

    public Car(final String cannotBeInjected) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How would I make `Car` (or a `Car` factory) injectable and still allow for an `Engine` instance to also be injected? A possible solution is to just assign the `cannotBeInjected` value via some setter after creation, but this just doesn't seem elegant.

Comment: Have you checked the assisted injection extension? https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject

Comment: Thanks, I did and it does seem to address my exact problem so I'm considering going that route. They mention making it "easier", making me wonder if there is a slightly less easy way without it that still works.

Comment: AssistedInjection is fabulous.  Without it you'd need to `CarProvider` (although NOT an implementation of `Provider<Car>` because you need your `get(String cannotBeInjected)` instead of the default `get()`.  At that point you're manually doing the assisted inject functionality though.